# Factorize current unique values in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am assigning an integer to various groups in a `pandas` `df`. I'm currently using `pd.factorize` for this. However, I'm hoping to account for *current* values only.

For instance, using the `df` below, a unique integer gets assigned to `Member`. This accumulates based on each unique value that appears. But I'm hoping to account for current values only. As in, if a value in `Member` does not appear again, then assign that integer to the next new value in `Member`. As C2 does not appear in the df again, I want to pass that integer to the next unique value in `Member`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({                                    
    'Period' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],                 
    'Member' : ['C1','C2','C4','C1','C2','C4','C1','C3','C4','C5'],                                                  
    })

df['Area'] = (pd.factorize(df['Member'])[0] + 1)
```

Out:

```
     Period Member  Area
0   1       C1     1   
1   1       C2     2   
2   1       C4     3   
3   2       C1     1   
4   2       C2     2      
5   2       C4     3   
6   3       C1     1   
7   3       C3     4   
8   3       C4     3   
9   3       C5     5
```

Intended:

```
   Period Member  Area
0  1       C1     1   
1  1       C2     2   
2  1       C4     3   
3  2       C1     1   
4  2       C2     2   
5  2       C4     3   
6  3       C1     1   
7  3       C3     2   
8  3       C4     3   
9  3       C5     4
```

This output assumes `C1,C3,C4,C5` all appear in following periods

Comment: why C3 is 2 ? ? in period 2

Comment: Yeh, I'll add something about this. Because `C2` doesn't appear again, `C3` should take over the assigned value. It's as if `C2` finishes and `C3` is taking over simultaneously. Could a combination work here. As in a nested group of strings? `C2, C3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my solution with explanation

Steps:

- get unique members and their counts
- create list of available area code equal to length of members, sorted in reverse order so that poping gives the minimum available id
- track assigned ids to member in "areas" dictionary
- decrement count of member when id is assigned to the member
- un-assign the area assigned to member when count of member is 0 and add that to available areas so that it can be re-used to new member

**NOTE**: This is according to logic you explained but gives different result that you shown above

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({                                    
    'Period' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],                       
    'Member' : ['C1','C2','C4','C1','C2','C3','C4','C1','C3','C4','C5'],                                                
    })

def assign_area(df):
    members, counts = pd.np.unique(df.Member, return_counts=True)
    member_counts = dict(zip(members, counts))
    areas = {}
    available_areas = list(range(len(members), 0, -1))
    area_col = []
    for member in df.Member:
        if member in areas:
            area = areas[member]
        else:
            area = available_areas.pop()
            areas[member] = area

        area_col.append(area)
        member_counts[member] -=1
        if member_counts[member] == 0:
            available_areas.append(area)
            available_areas.sort(reverse=True)

    df["area"] = area_col
    return df

assign_area(df)
```